In GNOME's Online Accounts, how do I add Fastmail's files, calendar and contacts? (WebDAV)
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ships with GNOME 46. GNOME 46 is the first version of GNOME that includes this feature:

A collection of additional improvements to Online Accounts have also
been made, thanks to funding from the Sovereign Tech Fund [...]:

A new WebDAV account type has been added, providing a generic method for integrating online contacts, calendars and files into your GNOME
experience.


Fastmail supports WebDav in its integrations for files, contacts and calendars. How do I enable them on Ubuntu 24.04? I've tried to go through the GNOME Online Accounts tool, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm entering the wrong information?

I don't have Ubuntu around to test at the moment, but you don't have this entry? https://i.sstatic.net/8MfoJDrT.png

@muru I do. I filled in all the fields, but it just doesn't work. The calendars and the contacts don't load, and the files entry in Nautilus gives an error. I'm not sure if I'm entering the correct configuration.

I initially starting drafting my own answer, thinking I could work it out, and after struggling to get it to work, I gave up, and I did not post my own answer.

Update needed for bug fix:
It looks like there is a bug in GNOME Online Accounts that prevents integration with Fastmail's calendar (CalDAV), contacts (CardDav), and files (WebDav). From the upstream changelog:

Overview of changes in 3.50.1

Improved WebDAV support for Fastmail and mailbox.org
Fixes for WebDAV discovery


Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ships with an update to gnome-online-accounts that fixes this bug. Make sure you version is equal to or greater than 3.50.4-0ubuntu2:
apt show gnome-online-accounts | grep Version

Configuration:
Open GNOME's settings, navigate to Online Accounts, and click "Calendar, Contacts and Files | WebDAV". Then enter these details:

Server Address: https://webdav.fastmail.com/
Username: Your Email address (e.g. username@domain.tld)
Password: Your DAV (CalDAV/CardDAV/WebDAV) app password


At this point, you should see your Fastmail account added to the list of accounts in GNOME's Online Accounts. Click on your Fastmail account, and make sure that "Calendar", "Contacts" and "Files" are all enabled:

Now you should be able to see Fastmail files in Nautilus, and Fastmail calendars in GNOME Calendar, and Fastmail contacts in GNOME Contacts.
You may have to leave the "Files", "Calendar (CalDAV)" and "Contacts (CardDAV)" fields blank for it to work correctly, despite these instructions in gnome-online-accounts' documentation.

In the meantime, I recommend using Thunderbird, which integrates well with Fastmail's contacts and calendars. The newer version of Thunderbird work out of the box with Fastmail's contacts and calendars.

If that was a bug fix release, you could file a big report asking for either the fix to be ported, or the new release to be added to backports. You might have some luck with it since this is part of the main desktop release

I filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/2072775

Thanks @muru ! The update got released in Ubuntu 24.04

Oh, wow, thank you for taking the time to report it!

This answer also works in Ubuntu 24.10, although I had to fill in the Calendar (CalDAV) server address field with https://caldav.fastmail.com/ to make it work.
